# C# An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I am trying to run my code as I click the button submit in asp web form. The error occurred as soon as I click the button Anyone knows the reason? the error message shows like this:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous
>   operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or
>   module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this
>   exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is
>   marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>.

aspx file:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Luis</h1>        
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="40px" Width="273px"></asp:TextBox>    
</div>
    <p>
       <input id="Submit1"  runat="server" type="submit" value="Check" onserverclick="Submit_Click"/></p>  
    <p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</p>
</asp:Content>
```

.cs file :

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
public async void Submit1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    string utterance = TextBox1.Text;

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

    // This app ID is for a public sample app that recognizes requests to turn on and turn off lights
    var luisAppId = "75bcaaff-1dc1-4dsa-adf7-63584cea339a";
    var subscriptionKey = "43314f19c5ecgdascba6a00f1d3cc3533";

    // The request header contains your subscription key
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

    // The "q" parameter contains the utterance to send to LUIS
    //queryString["q"] = "turn on the left light";

    // These optional request parameters are set to their default values
    queryString["timezoneOffset"] = "0";
    queryString["verbose"] = "false";
    queryString["spellCheck"] = "false";
    queryString["staging"] = "false";

    var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/" + luisAppId + "?" + queryString + "&q=" + utterance;
    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    var strResponseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Display the JSON result from LUIS
    //Console.WriteLine(strResponseContent.ToString());
    Label1.Text = strResponseContent.ToString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling an `ASYNC` method and the answer is in the error.

> ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>.