# How to call async on button click?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, angularjs

Im doing like below to call asyn on clikc

```
  private List<SuggestedItemsInput> suggestedItemAsync()
    {
        OHDWebService OHDService = new OHDWebService();
        List<SuggestedItemsInput> suggestedItemsList = OHDService.SaveSuggestedItems(ViewState["Body"].ToString(), hfdOrderRecordID.Value);
        return suggestedItemsList;
    }
```

onclick

```
  protected async void imgbtnClaim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Task<List<SuggestedItemsInput>> task = new Task<List<SuggestedItemsInput>>(suggestedItemAsync);
            task.Start();
            lblError.Text = "Please Wait. Proccessing...";
            List<SuggestedItemsInput> suggestedItems = await task;
            if (suggestedItems.Count > 0)
            {
```

but it is blocking UI, and thouswing error like below
[image]

How can achieve this?

Comment: instead of making the button's click `async` try creating it into a separate method and call it from your client-side(**angular**).

Comment: I'm using c#. I want it on onlick function

Comment: If you include  Async="true" in the Page Directive, it will work. Please refer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682205/c-sharp-an-asynchronous-operation-cannot-be-started-at-this-time

Answer (score 2):

Create a webmethod like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public async Task Yourmethod(string value)
{
value = "abc";
  return value;
}
```

And then from your front end use jquery to hit this method like this:

```
<script>
$(fucntion(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "..../Yourmethod",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) { }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it will fix error, but all UI will get block, thats why i neeed to saync in c#

Comment: create a webmehtod in any of your page and then from your front end send an ajax request to the webmethod to get data. In this way the UI wont be blocked. Let me know if you need an abstract example.

Comment: it would be great if you would give example.